# How to import documents that have arrays with the Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cosmosdb, database, nosql

I'm trying to import documents from a SQL Server database. Each document will have a list of products that a customer has bought, for example:

```
    {
        "name": "John Smith"
        "products": [
             {
                 "name": "Pencil Sharpener"
                 "description": "Something, this and that."
             },
             { 
                 "name": "Pencil case"
                 "description": "A case for pencils."
             }
        ]
    }
```

In the SQL Server database, the customer and products are stored in separate tables with a one-to-many relationship between the customer and products:

**Customer**

```
Id INT
Name VARCHAR
```

**Product**

```
Id INT
CustomerId INT (FK)
Name VARCHAR
Description VARCHAR
```

I've checked through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) , but can't see any mention of how to write the SQL query to map the one-to-many relationships to a single document.

I think there may be a way to do it as on the **Target Information** step (and when selecting **DocumentDB - Bulk import (single partition collections)**) there's the option to provide a [bulk insert stored procedure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/easily-transform-data-when-importing-to-azure-documentdb-2/). Maybe the products can be assigned to the document's products array from within there. I'm just not sure how to go about doing it as I'm new to Cosmos DB.

I hope that's clear enough and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you’d like to return products info formatted as json when you [import data from SQL Server using the Azure Cosmos DB: DocumentDB API Data Migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQL). Based on your ***customer*** and ***products*** table structure and your requirement, I do the following test, which works fine on my side. You can refer to it.

**Import data from SQL Server to JSON file**

[image]

[image]

**Query**

```
select distinct c.Name, (SELECT p.Name as [name], p.[Description] as [description] from [dbo].[Product] p where c.Id = p.CustomerId for JSON path) as products 
from [dbo].[Customer] c
```

**JSON output**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Jack",
    "products": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "John Smith",
    "products": "[{\"name\":\"Pencil Sharpener\",\"description\":\"Something, this and that\"},{\"name\":\"Pencil case\",\"description\":\"A case for pencils.\"}]"
  }
]
```

**Parsing the products**

On the 'Target Information' step, you'll need to use your own version of [BulkTransformationInsert.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/master/DocumentDb/Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb/BulkTransformationInsert.js). On line 32 is a 'transformDocument' function where you can edit the document. The following will parse the products and then assign them back to document before returning;

```
function transformDocument(doc) {
    if (doc["products"]) {
        let products = doc["products"];
        let productsArr = JSON.parse(products);
        doc["products"] = productsArr;
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fred. It's almost what I need but the products value is just a string and not an array. I suppose that's where I can use the stored procedure to convert it to an array.

Comment: In my reply, the ``products`` field is stored as string, but you can write your [User-defined functions (UDFs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) and use UDFs in queries to convert it to json array.

Comment: I don't think using a UDF would be the best approach for this as it's just over complicating queries and will mean that when adding new documents going forward they'd have to be stored as strings which would not only make working with the SDK more difficult using strongly typed objects but also mean that it's more complicated to add additional fields to each product and index them if needed at some point in the future. Cheers.

Comment: I need to do this on SQL Server 2014. Any ideas how this can be done as JSON is a SQL Server 2016 feature :-(

Comment: @FeiHan, that works very well! However, I am facing one issue here is that I cannot define my partition key correctly if I am using **single partition collections** with a bulk insert store procedure, I defined my partition key either with migration tool or within the store procedure but it doesn't generate correct version after migrating into cosmos DB, here is (my issue link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013043/cosmos-db-bulk-import-single-partition-collections-with-customized-partition/57032879#57032879]