# Cosmos DB - Bulk Import (single partition collections) with customized partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, database-migration

I am trying to migrate some data from a JSON file to Cosmos DB using *Data Migration Tool*, when I tried to define the partition key with either single or a combination of my column name, every time I am getting undefined partition key after migration, how could I correct this issue?

Note here I'll have to use **Bulk import (single partition collections)** options, because I need to execute my customized stored procedure for [nested array import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981322/how-to-import-documents-that-have-arrays-with-the-cosmos-db-data-migration-tool), I cannot use sequential record import as I know the same partition function works very well there.

So here I am setting my partition key to be "/item/vid":

[image]

After migration, my collection shows "_partitionKey" instead of "/item/vid" there:

[image]

Comment: do all your documents have a value in this path?  If this isn't a valid path for every single document in the collection it won't work.

Comment: You also need to change the format a little bit. The first forward slash is implied so you can change it to `item/vid`

Comment: @NickChapsas, thanks for your advice, unfortunately I tried with item/vid or even vid without the slash and both are not working for me...

Answer (score -1):

If you use Bulk import with migration tool, the partition key setting is for more than collection scenario.Please see the statement in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLBulkTarget):

> When you import to more than one collection, the import tool supports
>   hash-based sharding. In this scenario, specify the document property
>   you wish to use as the Partition Key. (If Partition Key is left blank,
>   documents are sharded randomly across the target collections.)

Back to your requirement,you could use [Sequential Record Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLSeqTarget).

[image]

You need to create collection first and set the partition key as `/item/vid`.

***My test json file:***

[image]

***Result:***

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation, however here I have to using **single partition collection**, I know that partitioned collection would work but I need use a custom store procedure script for my Bulk Insert. The **Partitioned Collection** does not have this option.